# jquery script to monitor disqus comment addition?

Tags: jquery, disqus

I would like to write a small script to monitor the disqus comments added on a page and fire some notification callbacks whenever new comments are added.

The simplest way for me to do it would be to periodically monitor the contents of the **#dsq-comments** div and trigger the callback whenever its html content changes.

While this will work, i'am wondering if there are any cleaner methods out there ?.

---

**Edit :** As suggested by @Pekka i implemented the onNewComment callback on my [page](http://www.kettik.com/go/asia/china/zhejiang/hangzhou/photos/92) and it works beautifully. This was one of my major concerns about integrating Disqus to my [site](http://www.kettik.com) and now i have a workable solution.

```
function disqus_config() {
  this.callbacks.onNewComment = [function() {
       $.get("/notifications/newcomment?...", function(data) {
       });
  }];
}
```

Comment: What's stopping an attacker from taking your onNewComment callback, saving it to his own function, and running it nonstop? This seems to violate the idempotence of GET requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be an `onNewComment` callback. See [How can I capture Disqus commenting activity in my own analytics tool?](http://docs.disqus.com/help/60/)

[This blog post](http://blog.slashpoundbang.com/post/2592867566/disqus-the-missing-manual) does a good job at documenting it.

Comment: Thank you... That definitely helped.

Comment: I just implemented the onNewComment callback on my webpage [link](http://www.kettik.com/go/asia/china/zhejiang/hangzhou/photos/92) and it works beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

Disqus commenting activity can be captured via callbacks, by using:

```
function disqus_config() {
  this.callbacks.onNewComment = [function() { trackComment(); }];
}
```

Where you will replace **trackComment();** by your own function.

Here is an example that loads Disqus comments dynamically using JavaScript, where you can find the **discus_config** function that will be fired when a new comment is added.

```
var loadDisqus = function() {
  window.disqus_identifier = 'your thread id';
  window.disqus_shortname = 'disqus_shortname';
  window.disqus_url = 'http://your_domain.com/path';
  window.disqus_title ='page title';
  window.disqus_config = function() {
    this.callbacks.onNewComment = [function() { myFunction() }];
  };

  (function() {
    var dsq = document.createElement('script');
    dsq.type = 'text/javascript';
    dsq.async = true;
    dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] ||
      document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
  })();

};
```